# Broken URL Finder?

Tags: dead-links

Is there a broken-URL finder application that I could use to scan a website for broken links? (A Mac application would be better.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For Windows users: [Xenu](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html)

For *nix/Mac: [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) (usually installed by default)

---

**Update:** Typical `wget` usage:

`wget -r --spider -b -o /var/tmp/wget.log http://target.site.com/`

- `-r` - Recursive download
- `--spider` - Check downloaded content for new links, then discard
- `-b` - Run in the background
- `-o /var/tmp/wget.log` - Target log file
- `http://target.site.com/` - Replace with the site you want to check

wget will create a log file detailing the status codes reported while downloading content from the target site - note that this method will catch links to nonexistent content from within the domain, however, off-site links will not be checked (which is why it pays to monitor your site's error logs).

Comment: Xenu is the most simplest and most useful tool that you can find for Win. I think that it also works under Wine for Linux.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to use wget for this.

Comment: The wget link is dead :)

Comment: @Tshepang - Updated as requested.

Answer (score 1):

Google Webmaster tools will report on broken links.  It's a simple tool, free to install to a website.....and platform agnostic.  If you're not already using it, it can help you boost your SEO and useability as well.

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en

Comment: Agree, but it can detect broken links only some time after you publish the site; by then some people will have already clicked on them and been disappointed.

Answer (score 1):

This recursive HTML validator: http://htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/

should show you broken links among other errors. The tool can also be installed locally.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try A1 Website Analyzer (Windows tool, but can run in VMWare/Fusion under Mac) It can tell you of all URL references site-wide (e.g. which pages link to a 404 URL + usually also line numbers), HTML/CSS errors etc.

Answer (score 1):

The [W3C Link Checker](http://validator.w3.org/checklink/) is one of the oldest online services that checks for broken links.